# Wrap text next to a button

Tags: button, text, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

Given something like:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  Some lengthy amount of text goes here.
</div>
```

I want the text to automatically wrap next to the button, instead of starting next to it and wrapping underneath it.  It appears with the default alignment, the text of the button is vertically aligned with the text next to it - but the button consumes additional vertical space for the button background.  I want the text to use that space - instead of only seeing a single available line.  It looks to me my text should be able to wrap at least once if not twice next to the button without consuming additional vertical space.

I've tried just wrapping the button & text in separate divs - but then the text appears under the button.  There's obviously something I'm missing - I either want to do this using native bootstrap or a simple inline style - I don't want to modify css.

The default:
    [**---button top margin--**]
    [**---------SUBMIT---------**] Normal text aligns with button text
    [**button bottom margin**]
    and then wraps beneath button like this.

Desired:
    [**---button top margin--**] If the text is long enough it should wrap
    [**---------SUBMIT---------**]  in this space and automatically
    [**button bottom margin**] center vertically against button

Let's see if I can express it differently - the button element occupies a certain vertical space, which is typically greater than just the vertical height of the text.  I want to have a text area next to the button that has the same vertical height as the total button - not just the button text.

Comment: Can you create a plunker for this? It would be better understood there

Comment: I'm not sure how - if I could express this properly in HTML then I probably wouldn't be asking this question!  I tried making a .PNG - but I don't have the reputation currently to upload/link an image.

Comment: I changed my text art a little - hopefully it's a little clearer now.